# Supersequence from a bag of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, graph

Given a string s, what is the most efficient way of identifying the shortest supersequence of s from a bag of strings? Also, the last character of s should match the last character of the superstring.

Comment: Do you mean, that you have a bag like `{"abbc", "abbbbb", "ba"}` and a string like `"bb"` and wants to find out that `"abbc"` is the shortest superstring of `"bb"` in the bag? You can do this in `O(|s|)` if you store your strings in a proper datastructure.

Comment: Not quite @ThomasAhle, in your example, the output must be 'abbbbb' because the bb and the output must have the same last character.

Comment: Ok, so the `s` has to be a postfix. And with `{"abb", "abba", "aabb", "a"}` the answer would be `"abb"`, right? That'll make the problem even easier.

Comment: With one occurrence each of `supersequence` and `superstring`, this question isn't far from confusing: an example using a set like [Thomas Ahle's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502695/supersequence-from-a-bag-of-strings#comment10540615_8502695) and string `ab` might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless i misunderstood it, this problem is most certainly in P.

A naive approach would be:

1. Take all strings in B ending with same character as s. Call this new bag B'. Can be done in O(|B|)
2. Select all strings that are supersequences of s in the bag B'. 
      It can be done in O(|B'|* max(|z|)) for z in B. Testing if a given string s is a subsequence of another string z can be done in O(|z|)
3. Select the shortest one of previously found strings (in O(|B'|))

Where |x| means size of x.

You can combine those steps, but it's O(|B| * max(|z|)) anyway.

Comment: What if there aren't strings in the bag that are supersequences of the strings ending in some character?  If there isn't one, you cannot enumerate all possible strings in polynomial time, since there are exponentially many of them.

Comment: @templatetypedef then the answer is 'such supersequence does not exist'. OP is looking for supersequence af a given string in the bag, that's also given. If he doesn't find it, so be it.

Comment: Whoops... I misread the question!  I thought the OP was asking to find, given a bag of strings, the shortest supersequence of the bag.  That problem is NP-hard.  The actual question isn't too difficult.  My apologies!

Comment: yeah, that one is NP-hard. I started doubting myself after seeing 2 answers mentioning it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bag doesn't change very often, I would construct a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) and search it with A*.

Answer (score 0):

Run through every string in the bag, checking if `s` is a substring using a fast string search like KMP. Check which of the superstrings is shortest. This is `O(Σlength of strings in bag)`.

If you need to do the search a multiple of times, you can construct a suffix trie for each string in the bag, and merge these. Then you can do lookups in `O(|s|)`.